# Convert string entered into input() back to two dimensional matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, matrix, codeskulptor

In a python program I am writing in CodeSkupltor3, data is stored as a single number in a list of lists (a 2d matrix). Because CodeSkulptor can't save files, I added an option for the user to export the data. It is printed out for the user to copy to the clipboard.

Here is an example of what the matrix might look like:

> [[0, 3, 4, 3, 2], [1, 2, 1, 2, 3], [3, 3, 3, 1, 2], [3, 4, 0, 3, 2], [2, 2, 2, 1, 0]]

However, the number of lists in the main list can vary, as do the number of integers in the sub-lists.

The user should be able to paste the data back into the program when prompted by an `input()` statement. Because all of the data passed into the input statement is in string format, it needs to be converted back into a matrix to use.

CodeSkulptor doesn't have `num.py` or `eval()`. I have tried using various combinations of `string.split()`, but no combination that I've tried breaks them up correctly. I also tried using `list()`, but the result is that each character in the string becomes an item in the list:

> ['[', '[', '0', ',', ' ', '3', ',', ' ', '4', ',', ' ', '3', ',', ' ', '2', ']', ',', ' ', '[', '1', ',', ' ', '2', ',', ' ', '1', ',', ' ', '2', ',', ' ', '3', ']', ',', ' ', '[', '3', ',', ' ', '3', ',', ' ', '3', ',', ' ', '1', ',', ' ', '2', ']', ',', ' ', '[', '3', ',', ' ', '4', ',', ' ', '0', ',', ' ', '3', ',', ' ', '2', ']', ',', ' ', '[', '2', ',', ' ', '2', ',', ' ', '2', ',', ' ', '1', ',', ' ', '0', ']', ']'

How do I turn a string back into a matrix?

Comment: Does passing the input string into `json.loads()` do the trick?

Comment: @SuperShoot It does, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution :

```
a = '[[0, 3, 4, 3, 2], [1, 2, 1, 2, 3], [3, 3, 3, 1, 2], [3, 4, 0, 3, 2], [2, 2, 2, 1, 0]]'

lst_lst = []
for i in a[:-1].replace('[', '').split(']'):
    lst = []
    for carac in i:
        if carac not in [',', ' ']:
            lst.append(int(carac))
    lst_lst.append(lst)
lst_lst
-> [[0, 3, 4, 3, 2], [1, 2, 1, 2, 3], [3, 3, 3, 1, 2], [3, 4, 0, 3, 2], [2, 2, 2, 1, 0]]
```

Comment: SuperShoot already gave an answer that is shorter, but thanks for going through the effort to help.

Comment: This solution produce an extra line:

    [[0, 3, 4, 3, 2],
     [1, 2, 1, 2, 3],
     [3, 3, 3, 1, 2],
     [3, 4, 0, 3, 2],
     [2, 2, 2, 1, 0],
     []]

https://py3.codeskulptor.org/#user303_9giPZzJby9C1P2v.py